# 1.9.0.1 shopping cart rules using stop further rule processing

Tags: discount

Would someone please share his knowledge in setting up discount:

Tried like 1000x combinations, but I cant get it to work as expected, so pls tell me if it is possible or not:

```
   I have coupon-codes 50%,30%,20%,10% - Priority high (works standalone)
   I have a 10% discount on a specific category if product form other    category is in cart. - Priority mid (works standalone)
   I have mass discount 3 5% and 10 10% (works standalone)
```

Now when all comes together I need the following:

```
   1. Discount of discount code on all items
   2. Discount of 10% specific discount on specific items
   3. STOP mass discount from being discounted
```

Any suggestions? :)

Thx in forward

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out ... somehow... the cart rule logic in 1.9.0.1 is wrong.

You can get a fix here. Worked 100% perfect from start then.

https://github.com/husseycoding/cartrulefix

So for everyone struggling problems with cart rules in 1.9.0.1 while using "stop further rule processing" -> use this fix!