# How to exclude catalog-price-rule reduced items from a shopping card discount rule?

Tags: extensions, shopping-cart-price-rules, catalog-price-rules, discount, price-rules

we are desperately looking for a shopping cart sales rule and a extension that allows us to do the following:

We want to offer a shopping card coupon code (-15%) which can only be applied to regularly priced (full price) articles. This means that old items which are reduced by a catalog price rule (-30%) are excluded and cannot be reduced any further.

At the moment, our settings only allow

- either to apply the shopping cart discount to all articles (including the items that are already reduced by the catalog price rule)
- or if I set the condition "special price =0 " it doesn't work at all since we're reducing with catalog rules and not with individual special prices.

Can anyone recommend a solution or Extension to work with?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you have to:

Set the -30% rule priority 0 and with option "stop further rule processing"

And

Set the -15% rule priority 1

If you use 1.9.0.x be aware of a bug in that function I addressed here:
[1.9.0.1 shopping cart rules using stop further rule processing](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/36829/1-9-0-1-shopping-cart-rules-using-stop-further-rule-processing/36932#36932)

Answer (score 0):

Similar question & answer over here: [Disable catalog price rule on coupon code](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/44937/disable-catalog-price-rule-on-coupon-code)

I wanted to do the same thing as you.

But as far as I can tell, there's no way for a shopping cart rule to determine whether or not an item has a price being updated by a catalog price rule. (I'm hoping I'm wrong on this.)