# Disable catalog price rule on coupon code

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, catalog-price-rules

Before I start to code this I just wanted to ask:
is it possible to create a shopping price rule that will disable catalog price rule calculations?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately NO.
Catalog price rules an cart price rules are independent.
The catalog rules are parsed separately via the price index and recalculated every night.
The final price of a product may or may not be influenced by a catalog rule.
The cart rules, don't care where the final price comes from. they just use it. So there is no way to determine if a catalog rule was applied to the price and disable it on the fly.
Also you cannot increase prices (not by default at least) by using the cart rules. You can only decrease them.

Comment: I was able to achievie things I've wanted on product and cart level. Also checkout worked fine with this modification. All I did was disable the CatalogRule Observer on some session conditions.

Comment: But there is another problem. Product listing collection takes price from another model and once I find where I'll submit my solutions as a community extension.

Comment: is any alternative solution in there?

Answer (score 0):

I post a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11718504/catalog-price-rule-vs-shopping-cart-rule/34099115#34099115

The idea came from Marshall Thornton' blog: http://www.magentotips.info/modules/catalog-shopping-cart-pricing-rules-stacking/#.VmIev98rKV4

Basicaly you need to extend Mage_SalesRule_Model_Validator::process() method

Comment: Did you delete your solution in the linked answer? I can't seem to find it anymore.