# Magento Shopping Cart Price Rule - Discounting the wrong amount

Tags: price, rules

We have a Magento store running 1.9 Community version.

We have a number of discount codes we publish in magazines, this morning we noticed however instead of giving a 10% discount it's giving a little bit more than it should...

Check this screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LY1Si.png

10% of £97.87 = £9.79 - no problem

£97.87 minus the discount rate £9.79 does not equal £86.12

This is the settings for the code:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSxf1.png
What are we doing wrong here? I am at a total loss.

Comment: maybe helpful http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/36829/1-9-0-1-shopping-cart-rules-using-stop-further-rule-processing

Answer (score 1):

Here's what happens:

- You have 20% VAT.
- Your discount is set to be calculated on price including VAT: 9.79
- Your product price excluding VAT: 81.55
- Your discount is set to apply at subtotal, subtotal is excluding VAT: 81.55 - 8.79 = 71.77
- Grand total is subtotal after discount plus VAT: 71.77 * 1.20 = 86.12

So your fix is to calculate discount price excluding VAT or apply at subtotal including tax.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the discount it is subtracting adds some tax? There's a setting in config->sales->tax that says to calculate tax before or after discount and the setting below it specifies whether you calculate tax in the discount.

Comment: I've done the maths on this, it was also my first thought. It does not matter either way, the amount will be the same.

Comment: They shouldn't be the same if you change the setting.. are you sure you are using the correct configuration scope?

Comment: we have the same problem - choosing subtotal always uses excl tax